# Can I avoid Golang modules cache to be stored in a built Docker image and maybe reuse the host's cache?

Tags: docker

I want to build a Docker image of an application (hugo), which should use pages generated on-the-fly by some program written in Golang from some of the data which the application needs (i.e. from a page template within a folder of ready HTML pages). When the go tool runs, it needs some modules downloaded and stored in Golang's system cache. They can be pretty big and are not needed in the final Docker image. How can I avoid them being included?
I know I can use multistage images and the `COPY --from=` an intermediate image, but it seems improper.
I have tried using `RUN --mount=type=tmpfs,target=~/.cache/go-build` in the Dockerfile Golang commands, <s>but files are still stored on the image. Shouldn't it avoid that?"</s> It works, but it would be nice to reuse the host's cache, actually (Jenkins agent or developer's machine). <s>What's wrong with my code?</s>

```
FROM registry.tools.cosmic.sky/core-community/baseimages/golang:1.18.10-alpine AS hugobase
...

ENV HUGO_ROOT=/var/hugo

WORKDIR ${HUGO_ROOT}

<Downloading Hugo here>
RUN ./hugo mod vendor get && chown -R 65534:65534 ${HUGO_ROOT}

COPY tools_version_scraper ${HUGO_ROOT}/tools_version_scraper
RUN cd ./tools_area_name_scraper; go mod download && \
  go run ./area_name_scraper.go \
    -src=${HUGO_ROOT}/content/en/docs/tenant-wiki/3-onboarding/3.1-new-team-onboarding/3.1.2-team-parent-namespace.template \
    -dest=${HUGO_ROOT}/content/en/docs/tenant-wiki/3-onboarding/3.1-new-team-onboarding/3.1.2-team-parent-namespace.md \
  && cd .. \
  && rm -fr ./tools_area_name_scraper

FROM hugobase AS test

<test stuff>

FROM hugobase AS main

USER 65534
EXPOSE 8080

ENTRYPOINT ["/var/hugo/hugo"]
CMD ["serve", "--bind", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "8080", "--verbose", "--verboseLog"]
```

Comment: Really quickly skimming through your requirements feels like you are looking for named volumes: https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#create-and-manage-volumes

Comment: Curious why you think the multistage and `COPY --from=` is improper as that use case is exactly what it was made for.

Comment: Hi, Rick. You are probably right. I was probably thinking wrongly about `COPY --from=`. The Golang tool (now replaced with a second type) generates/changes a file in `${HUGO_ROOT}/content`, and I was thinking of having to copy the generated file to then insert it into a fresh copy of `${HUGO_ROOT}/content` in the final image, when I can just copy the whole `${HUGO_ROOT}/content` folder. That would work; still I'd like to be able to use an external, more persistent cache, so I'll explore Benoit's suggestion.

Comment: Hi, Benoit. I'm in the `docker build` phase, not `docker run`. There is no named volume option, in that phase. https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#mount-types

Comment: Hey @Marco so you probably want to adjust the structure of your Dockerfile a little bit, to actually make use of its potential. You are using the same image over and over and just call it different stages. The better option is to perform all required actions in the first stage and then start with a clean an minimal image as second stage, add hugo to it, copy the content from the first stage and then run it. Does that make sense, or would a longer answer help you more?

Comment: Hi, Rick. Yes, it makes sense. I've done like that, eventually, though it feels like the Docker folks could make a _docker build_ option available to mount cache/host folders available by just specifying them on the build command-line.

Answer (score 0):

`--mount=type=tmpfs,target=~/.cache/go-build` actually does most of what I want, which is to not include in the image the files generated in the specified folder, while sharing them across builds on the same machine. It just cannot be pointed to a specific folder, like a Jenkins agent's own Golang cache, but it's good enough. See https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#run---mounttypecache for options.